# Tracking True/False dataset in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a coding quiz and using true/ false datasets in HTML to define the answer. My question is, how would I utilize these datasets to track true/ false in JS? My end goal is to display the score of the quiz.

Here's what it looks like so far:

```
<div class="post" id="question1" style="display: none;">
        <h3>Question 1:</h3>
        <h4>What does css stand for?</h4>
        <button onclick="display2()" data-answer="true" class="answer-btn">
          Casscading Style Sheet
        </button>
        <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Condensed Style Sheet
        </button>
        <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Cooperative Sea Shanty
        </button>
        <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Colonial Short Shorts
        </button>
      </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var dataTrue
function dataTrue () {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName(data-answer || true, score + 20));
}
var score = 0 + dataTrue();
```

Comment: So you're storing the answer to the question directly on the HTML element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` and attributes to access the answer:

```js
var answer = question1.querySelector('[data-answer=true]').innerText
console.log("correct answer was:"+answer)
```

```html
<div class="post" id="question1" style="display: none;">
  <h3>Question 1:</h3>
  <h4>What does css stand for?</h4>
  <button onclick="display2()" data-answer="true" class="answer-btn">
          Casscading Style Sheet
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Condensed Style Sheet
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Cooperative Sea Shanty
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Colonial Short Shorts
        </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a click listener, then access the dataset through `e.target.dataset.answer`. I went ahead and added another question and a final page to show one way of tracking questions and scores.

```js
let score = 0,
  onQuestion = 0
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.question')[onQuestion].classList.add('active')
  document.querySelectorAll('.question button').forEach(b => {
    b.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (e.target.dataset.answer === 'true') {
        console.log('correct!');
        score += 20;
        document.querySelectorAll('.score').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = score);
      } else console.log('Failed!');
      document.querySelector('.question.active').classList.remove('active');
      document.querySelectorAll('.question')[++onQuestion] ? .classList.add('active')


    })
  })
})
```

```css
.question {
  display: none;
}

.question.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="post question" id="question1">
  <h3>Question 1:</h3>
  <h4>What does css stand for?</h4>
  <button data-answer="true" class="answer-btn">
          Casscading Style Sheet
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Condensed Style Sheet
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Cooperative Sea Shanty
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Colonial Short Shorts
        </button>
</div>

<div class="post question" id="question2">
  <h3>Question 2:</h3>
  <h4>What does abc stand for?</h4>
  <button data-answer="true" class="answer-btn">
          Always Be Closing
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Alphabets Be Cool
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Arnold Bites Charlie
        </button>
  <button data-answer="false" class="answer-btn">
          Arny's Bitter Cheeses
        </button>
</div>

<div class="post question" id="question2">
  <h1>Quiz Complete. Your score: <span class='score'></span></h1>
</div>
<hr>
<div>Your score: <span class='score'>0</span></div>
```